# Why opening a file through Action in ASP.NET MVC application works in IE and Firefox but not in chrome?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-4.5

I am trying to open a file in View instead of downloading it.The code works fine in IE and Firefox but it downloads the file in Chrome instead of opening it.

Here is my code.

```
//OpenWord Action
        string filePath = @"G:\WordDemo\DocXExample.doc";
        var doc = DocX.Create(fileName)
        doc.InsertParagraph("This is my first paragraph"+person.FirstName+"  "+person.LastName);
        doc.Save();

        string fileName = "DocXExample.doc";
        byte[] fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filePath);
     string mimeType = "application/msword";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
return File(fileData, mimeType);
```

Any Help and Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Does your version of chrome have a ms word viewer?

Comment: @Wimmel :Thanks for commenting but IE and Firefox are using the MS Word application of system so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: @PratikPatil So despite your question title asking about "opening a file in browser" and claiming that works in IE and Firefox, you now say in your comment that the file never opens in any browser, but instead always in a separate application, and that's what you're looking for in Chrome as well? That's a totally different question. I strongly recommend editing your question to clearly ask what you're after.

Comment: I have edited the question, is it clear enough now?

Comment: I think it's probably clear enough now what you want. I suspect what you want is not possible though, so I don't see much chance of this getting real answers, just explanations and/or workarounds, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work consistently across devices and clients cos it is dependent on plugins installed for the client.

Try this.

Host the word document in your site so it is available for download via say http://www.example.com/path/mydocument.doc

In your View add this iframe

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.example.com/path/mydocument.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but it didn't worked. `<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=file:///G:/WordDemo/DocXExample.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>`

Comment: It will not work with url=file:///G:/. It should be available in the web via http or https. See the url in my sample code.

Comment: Thanks for your help but that is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: After lot of googling I found no answer to this problem.So I will have to go with google docs but while doing it I am facing "No Preview Available" error can you please help @JerryJoseph                                                                 Here is my code `<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://localhost:57063/DocXExample.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>`

Comment: It is cos Google is not able to parse the document. You can access the document via localhost but not Google. So upload the docment to your server first and try with the externally reachable URL like in the example I gave.